# Nhibernate queryover filter based on count of child collection

Tags: sql, nhibernate, queryover, nhibernate-projections

Ultimately I want to filter all parent objects that have less than 2 children.

I'm building a search screen with a grid dashboard, which uses the following logic as a example of how to build a query.

```
var query = Session.QueryOver<Parent>(() => parentAlias);

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SearchCriteria.OpenedBy))
    query.Where(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Property<Parent>(x => x.OpenedBy), SearchCriteria.OpenedBy));

if (SearchCriteria.OpenedDateStart != null)
    query.Where(Restrictions.Ge(Projections.Property<Parent>(x => x.OpenedAt), SearchCriteria.OpenedDateStart));
```

This is working wonderfully right up until this point:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchCriteria.ChildrenAffected) && SearchCriteria.ChildrenAffected == "Multi")
    query.Where(() => parentAlias.Children.Count > 2);
```

It makes sense that .Count does't work, this isn't really linq. Also .Count() throws an error. Honestly, I feel like I've tried every combination of Restritions, JoinAlias, etc that I can think of, but I've gone off the path of educated attempts and into the realm wild guessing a long time ago.

How do I set up a query to filter out a parent based on the count of children in the QueryOver syntax?

-----NOTE -----
I Debated using linq after id gotten my list, but I'm doing paging in the query set up so the filter would be applied after the page came back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a subquery...

```
Children childrenAlias = null;
var subquery = QueryOver.Of<Children>(() => childrenAlias)
     .Where(() => childrenAlias.Parent.ID == parentAlias.ID)
     .ToRowCountQuery();
query.WithSubquery.WhereValue(2).Le(subquery);
```

Note that I don't know how to do `Count > 2`, so I'm doing `2 <= Count`, and there is the possibility that instead of

```
.Where(() => childrenAlias.Parent.ID == parentAlias.ID)
```

you can write

```
.Where(() => childrenAlias.Parent == parentAlias)
```

Mmmh... if you reall need Count > 2 you should be able to:

```
query.Where(Restrictions.Gt(Projections.SubQuery(subquery), 2));
```

or

```
query.WithSubquery.Where(() => subquery.As<int>() > 4);
```

(this one I haven't ever used... taken from http://blog.andrewawhitaker.com/blog/2014/10/24/queryover-series-part-8-working-with-subqueries/)

Comment: @Seth You'll have to build the join through the many-to-many table in the subquery

Comment: Ok, Soon as I get it working I'll mark this correct. It looks right.

Comment: Struggling with the join clause, running into getting the entire table rowcount. The rest of the search seems to work fine with the subquery.